# Mobile Offline GPS lat, lng, storage using Phonegap and Sencha?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, cordova, extjs

Is it possible to store offline gps information on iphone / android if the mobile development is implemented using Sencha and Phonegap ?

Is there a way to implement a native application using html5 and css3 that can access resources such as gps and camera to store that data offline?

Im researching if i should go native or not, any suggestions are kindly appreciated.

Comment: "a native application using html5 and css3" isn't that phonegap? Btw: what exactly do you try to do?

Comment: I want to know for sure if gps data and picture data can be stored offline within a phonegap + sencha development so i can take the decission of using that paradigm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhoneGap absoulutely supports this scenario by persisting the data to the local database of the device.
You can find more info (including code snippets) in the [PhoneGap API reference](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage).

If have ever seen SQL queries, database operations will be a piece of cake for you. Your app will run on Android and iPhone as well.

Comment: excellent, your answer clarified everything, i was looking also to the-m-project.org, it is a framework also for generating native apps, has anyone tried it?